# Shell echo statement output

Tags: bash, shell

I am new to shell scripting. I have the following shell script -

```
psql database connection -t -c "SELECT bucket FROM all_buckets GROUP BY bucket" | while read bucket_var ; 
do
if [ ! -z "$bucket_var" ]
then

echo "Bucket being processed is - $bucket_var"

fi

done
```

This is the output I am getting -

```
+ '[' '!' -z Endography ']'
+ echo 'Bucket being processed is - Endography'
Bucket being processed is - Endography
+ read bucket_name_var
```

How do I just get this output instead -

```
Bucket being processed is - Endography (current date and time in CST)
```

Comment: is it the complete script you are posting, if not please post the complete script.

Comment: I assume you want the `bash` script to replace the string `current date and time in CST` ... please update the question with the format of the date/time you're looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have `set -x` in your script. That makes it echo all commands as they are executed. Remove that line (or do `set +x` to undo the setting).

From the `man` page of `set`:

`-x` After expanding each simple command, for command, case command, select command, or arithmetic for command, display the expanded value of PS4, followed by the command and its expanded  arguments  or  associated word list.

To add the current date and time, use `date`:

```
echo "Bucket being processed is - $bucket_var ($(date))"
```